# Error installing Openai in PyCharm CE 2023.2.3 (Python 3.12). (aiohttp whl error)

Tags: openai-api, aiohttp

I am hoping someone can help me figure out the best course of action for an issue I am having.  I am trying to play with the ChatGPT API.  As suggested, I am doing an install, which seems to through an error.  Please see the log below.   I then tried to install alternative versions of aiohttp (3.8.1 through to 3.8.6) but they all throw the same error.   Based on some reading, i could potentially need to role back to an older version of python. I am not super experienced though, and also see some info on deprecation of something in cython, so figured I would check with the group here to see if that is my only course of action.

Log

```
 pip install --upgrade openai           
Collecting openai
  Downloading openai-0.28.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.20 (from openai)
  Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting tqdm (from openai)
  Downloading tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.6/57.6 kB 65.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting aiohttp (from openai)
  Downloading aiohttp-3.8.6.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.4/7.4 MB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl.metadata (33 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.5/61.5 kB 646.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Downloading urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests>=2.20->openai)
  Downloading certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Downloading attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.2/61.2 kB 587.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Downloading multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 51.3/51.3 kB 6.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Downloading async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Downloading yarl-1.9.2.tar.gz (184 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 184.7/184.7 kB 553.5 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Downloading frozenlist-1.4.0.tar.gz (90 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 90.7/90.7 kB 630.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp->openai)
  Downloading aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Downloading openai-0.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 77.0/77.0 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.6/62.6 kB 640.6 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 78.3/78.3 kB 753.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading async_timeout-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Downloading certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 158.3/158.3 kB 691.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.1-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (119 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 119.9/119.9 kB 196.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (124 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 124.2/124.2 kB 811.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [188 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/worker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/multipart.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_response.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_ws.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/test_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tracing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_middlewares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_app.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/streams.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_protocol.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/log.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_request.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_websocket.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_proto.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/locks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_runner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/base_protocol.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_reqrep.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_log.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/resolver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/formdata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/payload_streamer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_routedef.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/connector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/client_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/typedefs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/hdrs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/web_fileresponse.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_writer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/tcp_helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/helpers.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/http_parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/cookiejar.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/pytest_plugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/abc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp/*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp/_cparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_find_header.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_headers.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_helpers.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_http_writer.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/_websocket.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      copying aiohttp/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_cparser.pxd.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_find_header.pxd.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyi.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_helpers.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/_websocket.pyx.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      copying aiohttp/.hash/hdrs.py.hash -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/travislueth/PycharmProjects/ChatGPT/chatgpt/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c aiohttp/_websocket.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/aiohttp/_websocket.o
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1475:17: warning: 'Py_OptimizeFlag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        if (unlikely(!Py_OptimizeFlag)) {
                      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/pydebug.h:13:1: note: 'Py_OptimizeFlag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) PyAPI_DATA(int) Py_OptimizeFlag;
      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2680:27: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          return likely(dict) ? __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict) : 0;
                                ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2692:36: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          return (dictptr && *dictptr) ? __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(*dictptr) : 0;
                                         ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2696:56: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          if (unlikely(!dict) || unlikely(tp_dict_version != __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)))
                                                             ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2741:9: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              __PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED(
              ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1125:16: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED'
          if (likely(__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(DICT) == __pyx_dict_version)) {\
                     ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:2741:9: warning: 'ma_version_tag' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              __PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED(
              ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1129:30: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_PY_DICT_LOOKUP_IF_MODIFIED'
              __pyx_dict_version = __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(DICT);\
                                   ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:1118:65: note: expanded from macro '__PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION'
      #define __PYX_GET_DICT_VERSION(dict)  (((PyDictObject*)(dict))->ma_version_tag)
                                                                      ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/cpython/dictobject.h:22:5: note: 'ma_version_tag' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
          Py_DEPRECATED(3.12) uint64_t ma_version_tag;
          ^
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12/pyport.h:317:54: note: expanded from macro 'Py_DEPRECATED'
      #define Py_DEPRECATED(VERSION_UNUSED) __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                           ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3042:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3097:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3238:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3293:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      aiohttp/_websocket.c:3744:47: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
          const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)b)->ob_digit;
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      6 warnings and 5 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for frozenlist: filename=frozenlist-1.4.0-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl size=84986 sha256=b708c60a74ddeeb0888d2b0ddc1504fd879d7
  Stored in directory: /Users/trav/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/f1/9c/94/9386cb0ea511a93226456388d41d35f1c24ba15a62ffd7b1ef
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for multidict: filename=multidict-6.0.4-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl size=48165 sha256=afc7344decbaa44b06dad964ac
  Stored in directory: /Users/trav/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/f6/d8/ff/3c14a64b8f2ab1aa94ba2888f5a988be6ab446ec5c8d1a82da
  Building wheel for yarl (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for yarl: filename=yarl-1.9.2-cp312-cp312-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl size=98522 sha256=66feda1a1cbdef60e24215208
  Stored in directory: /Users/trav/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/84/e3/6a/7d0fa1abee8e4aa3
Successfully built frozenlist multidict yarl
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried installing multiple versions of aiohttps
Each time I did a cache purge to ensure it installed the right version and got similar errors each time.   I tried 3.8.1 through 3.8.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning C4996: 'Py\_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/\_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob\_digit': is not a member of '\_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)

Answer (score 0):

Try using for `python 3.12`

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```